# Overriding form submit event with jQuery (1.3.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I cannot find a solution for that, I need to override a previously set submit event handler. In my example, I have a iframe page, with their own submit (which can have validation errors, and return false). So, I'm need to do:

```
$('<iframe></iframe>')
    .load(function() {
       content = $(this).contents()
       form = content.find('form')
       previous_form_submit = .... //This is my question
       form.unbind("submit")
       form.submit(function() {
           var valid = previous_form_submit()
           if (valid) {
             $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data) {
                //do something
            })
        })
     })
```

Edit: To be more clearer, the problem is override the event, but without losing previous handler with validation.

Edit2: I'm using jQuery 1.3.2

I'm going to another kind of solution, but I felt curious about how can do that.

Comment: those variables ("content", "form", "previous_form_submit") should all be declared with the `var` keyword!  As it is now, they're global to the page!

Comment: Also: you're already calling "unbind", so is your question really about how to *save* any previous submit handler?

Comment: Yes, is just a extract from my original code. Yes, I mean: I need to override the current submit event handlers with mine, but I need to save previous handlers, for validation (in my example theres one previous handler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers are stored in the element's expando data store, accessible by [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), in this case, [`.data('events')`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for event handlers, then you do `.submit` for bound submit handlers, `.click` for clicks, etc.

---

**jQuery 1.4+ version:**

If the form had one submit handler it would look like this:

```
var oldHandler = form​​​​​​​​.data("events").submit[0].handler;
```

Otherwise you need to loop through them, using a [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for example:

```
$.each(form.data("events").submit, function(i, h) {    
  var handler = h.handler;
  //do something with handler
});
```

---

**jQuery 1.3.x version:**

Using a [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for example:

```
$.each(form.data("events").submit, function(i, h) {    
  var handler = h;
  //do something with handler
});
```

It's best to loop though here, as the indexes aren't cleaned up.  A handler may not be the first item, so `.submit[0]` might be `undefined`, even if there *is* a handler.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'm using jquery 1.3.2.

Comment: @Hugo - Updated to show the slightly different object layout in 1.3.2 :)

Comment: @Nick - Thanks again, but form.data("events") is returning nothing.
Edit: form.data("events") is undefined

Comment: Mmm.. seems that it doesn't work outside the iframe, in the parent page.

Comment: @Hugo - You can't cross event handlers in one window with another (not in this way), they're independent cache mechanisms for each jQuery instance...what are you ultimately trying to achieve here?  When I mean is that event handler references things in *that* page, you're likely to have all sorts of issues using it in any way in the parent.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a different approach for that. Basically, I'm trying to replace the normal submit of the pages render inside the iframe, with my custom.

Comment: @Hugo - In that case, why do you need the previous one, if you're going to replace it? :)

Comment: Because the previous one have validation.

Comment: @Hugo - Do you need your handler to run first?  You can just attach an *additional* handler with `.submit(function() { ..myCode... })` and it'll run after the handler that was there before.